# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xa5 in position 0: invalid start byte

Tags: python, json, unicode

I am using `Python-2.6 CGI` scripts but found this error in server log while doing `json.dumps()`,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/etc/mongodb/server/cgi-bin/getstats.py", line 135, in <module>
    print json.dumps(​​__get​data())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 231, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 201, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 264, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xa5 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

​Here, `​__get​data()` function returns a dictionary.

Before posting this question, I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6180521/unicodedecodeerror-utf8-codec-cant-decode-bytes-in-position-3-6-invalid-dat) question on SO. How do I resolve this error?

Comment: It looks like you have some string data in the dictionary that can't be encoded/decoded.  What's in the `dict`?

Comment: @mgilson yup master I understood the issue but donno how to deal with it..`dict` has `list, dict, python timestamp value `

Comment: to debug , put lines that throws error . It will be more useful .

Comment: @Pilot -- Not really.  The real problem is buried somewhere in `__getdata`.  I don't know *why* you're getting a non-decodable character.  You can try to come up with patches on the dict to make it work, but those are mostly just asking for more problems later.  I would try printing the dict to see where the non-ascii character is.  Then figure out how that field got calculated/set and work backward from there.

Comment: Master @mgilson can you please check updated question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x9c](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12468179/1677912).

Comment: I had that same error when trying to read a .csv file which had some non-ascii characters in it. Removing those characters (as suggested below) solved the issue.

Comment: **But I am not sure is it correct way to do it.** It is indeed...

Comment: There is a bug in Visual Studio 2022 using Python and UTF-8. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73125063/error-unicode-error-utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte-code-compilef-read/77065908#77065908

Answer (score 121, accepted):

The error is because there is some non-ascii character in the dictionary and it can't be encoded/decoded. One simple way to avoid this error is to encode such strings with `encode()` function as follows (if `a` is the string with non-ascii character):

```
a.encode('utf-8').strip()
```

Comment: Since UTF-8 is back-compatible with the oldschool 7-bit ASCII you should just encode everything. For characters in the 7-bit ASCII range this encoding will be an identity mapping.

Comment: This doesn't seem real clear.  When importing a csv file how do you use this code?

Comment: The same issue appears for me when executing an sqlalchemy query, how would I encode the query (has no .encode, since its not a string)?

Comment: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x9b in position 14050657: invalid start byte

Answer (score 404):

If you get this error when trying to read a csv file, the `read_csv()` function from `pandas` lets you set the encoding:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv(filename, encoding='unicode_escape')
```

Comment: Only if you using `pandas`

Comment: sorry, this didn't working, I again had the same error. but when I used ('filename.csv', engine ='python'). This worked.

Comment: works for pysrt too, pysrt.open(subfilename, encoding='unicode_escape') and I think this solution should work with Un-encoded text / plain text for any library that supports encoding on file open
"unicode_escape" will open file , but if you have non-ascii you should give specific encoding for example for Turkish   encoding='ISO-8859-9'

Comment: I had the same problem using pandas and this solution worked.  However, is there a way to change the file itself?  My csv file was generated by Excel and I don't see any special characters.  So I am thinking there must be a way to re-save this file so that I don't have to use 'unicode-escape'.

Comment: Also worked inside R with reticulate.

Answer (score 188):

By default open function has io attribute 'r' as in read only. This can be set to 'rb' as in read binary.

Try the below code snippet:

```
with open(path, 'rb') as f:
  text = f.read()
```

Comment: I had `r` instead of `rb`. thanks for the reminder to add `b`!

Comment: By default `open` function has 'r' as read only mode. `rb` stands for read binary mode.

Answer (score 56):

Your string has a non **`ascii`** character encoded in it.

Not being able to decode with **`utf-8`** may happen if you've needed to use other encodings in your code. For example:

```
>>> 'my weird character \x96'.decode('utf-8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 19: invalid start byte
```

In this case, the encoding is **`windows-1252`** so you have to do:

```
>>> 'my weird character \x96'.decode('windows-1252')
u'my weird character \u2013'
```

Now that you have `Unicode`, you can safely encode into **`utf-8`**.

Comment: I have created a simple page which may help establish the encoding of some unexpected "mystery bytes"; https://tripleee.github.io/8bit/

Comment: This solved it for my case with pd.read(), just switching to encoding='windows-1252' instead of encoding='utf-8'

Comment: How did you know that the encoding is `windows-1252`?

Comment: Because I created this example. I just chose an character encoded using something other than utf-8 to illustrate a decode error. There are libraries you can use to detect encodings. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436220/how-to-determine-the-encoding-of-text

Answer (score 41):

On read `csv`, I added an encoding method:

```
import pandas as pd
dataset = pd.read_csv('sample_data.csv', header= 0,
                        encoding= 'unicode_escape')
```

Answer (score 39):

This solution worked for me:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("training.csv", encoding = 'unicode_escape')
```

Answer (score 29):

Inspired by @aaronpenne and @Soumyaansh

```
f = open("file.txt", "rb")
text = f.read().decode(errors='replace')
```

Comment: I got "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'". Not sure what went wrong?

Comment: Did you include b to the "rb"? The b is for opening the file as byte-formated. If you just use r it is string, and don't include decode.

Answer (score 19):

Set default encoder at the top of your code

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("ISO-8859-1")
```

Comment: I think python3 doesn't have setdefaultencoding in sys module!

Answer (score 17):

**Simple Solution:**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('file_name.csv', engine='python')
```

Comment: The only solution that works for me of all those presented here.

Comment: This solution helped me open csv file with `korean` language in it. Thanks

Answer (score 16):

**As of 2018-05 this is handled directly with [`decode`, at least for Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#codecs.decode).**

I'm using the below snippet for `invalid start byte` and `invalid continuation byte` type errors. Adding `errors='ignore'` fixed it for me.

```
with open(out_file, 'rb') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line.decode(errors='ignore'))
```

Comment: Of course, this silently discards information. A much better fix is to figure out what's supposed to be there, and fixing the original problem.

Answer (score 16):

If the above methods are not working for you, you may want to look into changing the `encoding` of the `csv file` itself.

Using Excel:

1. Open `csv` file using `Excel`
2. Navigate to **File menu** option and click **Save As**
3. Click **Browse** to select a location to save the file
4. Enter intended filename
5. Select **`CSV (Comma delimited) (*.csv)`** option
6. Click **Tools** drop-down box and click **Web Options**
7. Under **Encoding** tab, select the option `Unicode (UTF-8)` from **Save this document as** drop-down list
8. Save the file

Using Notepad:

1. Open `csv file` using notepad
2. Navigate to **File** > **Save As** option
3. Next, select the location to the file
4. Select the Save as type option as All Files(*.*)
5. Specify the file name with `.csv` extension
6. From **Encoding** drop-down list, select `UTF-8` option.
7. Click Save to save the file

By doing this, you should be able to `import csv` files without encountering the `UnicodeCodeError`.

Comment: This worked for me while none of the above solutions did.

Answer (score 10):

The following snippet worked for me.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep = ';', encoding = 'latin1', error_bad_lines=False) #error_bad_lines is avoid single line error
```

Comment: error_bad_lines has been deprecated, use on_bad_lines instead, like = on_bad_lines = 'skip'

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Need to add: this does not help for me

Answer (score 8):

Following line is hurting JSON encoder,

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
now = datetime.datetime.strftime(now, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
print json.dumps({'current_time': now}) // this is the culprit
```

I got a temporary fix for it

```
print json.dumps( {'old_time': now.encode('ISO-8859-1').strip() })
```

Marking this as correct as a temporary fix (Not sure so).

Answer (score 4):

You may use any standard encoding of your specific usage and input.

**`utf-8`** is the default.

**`iso8859-1`** is also popular for Western Europe.

e.g: `bytes_obj.decode('iso8859-1')`

see: [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings)

Comment: Blindly guessing the encoding is likely to produce more errors. Selecting iso8859-1 or cp1251 etc without actually knowing which encoding the file uses will remove the symptom, but produce garbage if you guessed wrong. If it's just a few bytes, it could take years before you notice and fix the *real* error.

Answer (score 2):

After trying all the aforementioned workarounds, if it still throws the same error, you can try exporting the file as `CSV` (a second time if you already have).
Especially if you're using `scikit learn`, it is best to `import` the dataset as a `CSV file`.

I spent hours together, whereas the solution was this simple. Export the file as a CSV to the directory where `Anaconda` or your classifier tools are installed and try.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of looking for ways to decode a5 (Yen `¥`) or 96 (en-dash `–`), tell MySQL that your client is encoded "latin1", but you want "utf8" in the database.

See details in [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same error while trying to import to a pandas dataframe from an excel sheet on sharepoint. My solution was using engine='openpyxl'. I'm also using requests_negotiate_sspi to avoid storing passwords in plain text.

```
import requests
from io import BytesIO
from requests_negotiate_sspi import HttpNegotiateAuth
cert = r'c:\path_to\saved_certificate.cer'
target_file_url = r'https://share.companydomain.com/sites/Sitename/folder/excel_file.xlsx'
response = requests.get(target_file_url, auth=HttpNegotiateAuth(), verify=cert)
df = pd.read_excel(BytesIO(response.content), engine='openpyxl', sheet_name='Sheet1')
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file_name.csv', engine='python-fwf')
```

If it's not working try to change the `engine` to `'python'` or `'c'`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is simple: some non ascii text has been encoded to bytes with a different encoding from the one you are using. (Of course if you don't have "special-chars" the charset does not matter much)

Example:

```
my_text = "Temp in °"
my_encoded_text = bytes(my_text,'iso-8859-1')
my_encoded_text.decode('utf-8')
```

This will throw the error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb0 in position 8: invalid start byte

whereas if you use the same charset to decode it

```
my_text = "Temp in °"
my_encoded_text = bytes(my_text,'iso-8859-1')
my_encoded_text.decode('iso-8859-1')
```

> 'Temp in °'

If you don't know the charset that has been used to perform the encoding, and you're dealing with a file, then you can use 'chardet' (install it first wink, wink).

```
import chardet
file_name = 'the_file_you_want_to_read.csv'
with open(file_name, 'rb') as f:
    result = chardet.detect(f.read())

detected_charset = result['encoding']
```

You can use the detected_charset to decode the file.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i had to save the file as **UTF8 with BOM** not just as `UTF8 utf8` then this error was gone.

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't fit directly to the question, but I repeatedly get directed to this when I google the error message.

I did get the error when I mistakenly tried to install a Python package like I would install requirements from a file, i.e., with `-r`:

```
# wrong: leads to the error above
pip install -r my_package.whl

# correct: without -r
pip install my_package.whl
```

I hope this helps others who made the same little mistake as I did without noticing.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot answers here that suggest to use one encoding or the other to make the error go away. I think you really shouldn't do that. For example, if you're trying to load a CSV file into memory using pandas etc., then using encodings like `latin1` or `unicode_escape` will get rid of the error but will produce gibberish for the actual row that is giving the error and you will just silently lose data.

If you get this error and you absolutely know the problem is related to encoding, then the solution is to figure out the correct encoding; e.g. datasets are usually accompanied by another dictionary for the metadata; webpages have their encoding in their header etc., or just ask the people who prepared the data etc.

However, the error might also signal that what you're attempting is not supposed to be done. For example, if you try to decode an image file read as a bytes object, it will throw the error in the title, but realistically, you never are supposed to do it.

```py
with open("myimage.png", "rb") as f:
    data = f.read()

data.decode()  # UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

You probably want to read the image into a numeric array in the first place, so the solution is to use a dedicated image reader module instead and convert the data into an array without the middleman process of decoding a bytes.

```py
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
data = np.array(Image.open("myimage.png"))
```