# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x83 in position 1: invalid start byte

Tags: exception, python-3.4, word-cloud

I am new to Python and I am using python 3.4, on a windows 7 machines. I installed the module wordcloud using pip. However when I run my code:

```
import os
from scipy.misc import imread
from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS, ImageColorGenerator
import random
```

below is my output below:

```
     UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-1-af184f77eb1f> in <module>()
         18 import os
         19 from scipy.misc import imread
    ---> 20 from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS, ImageColorGenerator
         21 import random

    C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\wordcloud-1.2-py3.4-win-amd64.egg\wordcloud\__init__.py in <module>()
    ----> 1 from .wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS, random_color_func
          2 from .color_from_image import ImageColorGenerator
          3 
          4 __version__ = "1.2"
          5 

    C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\wordcloud-1.2-py3.4-win-amd64.egg\wordcloud\wordcloud.py in <module>()
     18 from PIL import ImageFont
     19 
---> 20 from .query_integral_image import query_integral_image
     21 
     22 item1 = itemgetter(1)

stringsource in init wordcloud.query_integral_image (wordcloud/query_integral_image.c:13415)()

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x83 in position 1: invalid start byte
```

What could be the problem and how do I resolve this issue? thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xa5 in position 0: invalid start byte](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22216076/unicodedecodeerror-utf8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xa5-in-position-0-invalid-s)