# Reading and writing UTF-8 from file

Tags: python-2.7, utf-8

I have some text encoded in UTF-8. 'Before – after.' It was fetched from the web. The '–' character is the issue. If you try to print directly from the command line, using copy and paste:

```
>>> text = 'Before – after.'
>>> print text
Before – after.
```

But if you save to a text file and try to print:

```
>>> for line in ('file.txt','r'):
>>>     print line
Before û after.
```

Im pretty sure this is some sort of UTF-8 encode/decode error, but it is eluding me. I have tried to decode, or re-encode but that is not it either.

```
>>> for line in ('file.txt','r'):
>>>     print line.decode('utf-8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 7: invalid start byte

>>> for line in ('file.txt','r'):
>>>     print line.encode('utf-8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 7: invalid start byte
```

Comment: did you try decoding it and then printing it out? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: just trying to fetch text from the web, save to txt document for processing later. When printing, it gets corrupted.

Comment: did you try decoding it? `line = line.decode('utf-8');`

Comment: Yes:`line=line.decode('utf-8')`; `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 7: invalid start byte`

Comment: How did you save it to a text file? How do you know you saved it as utf-8? I saved your string as utf-8 and it worked for me. Your method of decoding each line should work.

Comment: The reason why it works on the command line is a bit odd and a quirk of how unicode works on python 2 That "string" is really an encoded byte sequence. It looks right because its in the same encoding as your terminal. What is `sys.stdout.encoding` on your system?

Comment: As an aside, python 3 has been out for many years and has much more robust unicode support. Python 2 is legacy and should only be used when required.

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because a non-ascii character cannot be encoded or decoded. You can strip it out and then print the ascii values. 
Take a look at this question : [UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xa5 in position 0: invalid start byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22216076/unicodedecodeerror-utf8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xa5-in-position-0-invalid-s)

Comment: So why would it work with a direct cut and paste approach? >>> text = `'Before - after.'
>>> print text
Before - after.
>>> text.encode('utf-8')
'Before - after.'`

Comment: non-ascii text can be decoded. In python 2, the read got a binary string and it should be decoded. The error suggests that OP guessed the wrong encoding.

Comment: Read the first example : https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html 
Should be of use.