# Python3 executing a command on osx with os.popen give me a strange exception

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, macos

I'm executing a command in python using:

```
command = os.popen("sudo dd if=/path/to/downloaded.img of=/dev/rdiskN bs=1m").read()
```

I'm trying to create a bootable USB device with diskutil
but I'm getting this error and I don't know how to fix it

`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 4: invalid start byte`

**EDIT**

I solved by myself using subprocess event:

```
subprocess.check_output("command","to","execute"]).decode(errors='ignore')
```

Comment: Did you try putting the error through a Google search? What did you find?

Comment: I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22216076/unicodedecodeerror-utf8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xa5-in-position-0-invalid-s but I was not able to solve anyway