# Python3.7 i can't convert this byte to string

Tags: python, string, byte

I have this code:

```
byte = b'\x7f\x9fKL\xaa\xe6\xc8\x8d\xdf865\xf1s\t`R\xd6\xe8\x9c\x07\xae\x97\xe4\x0e\xe6\x08_CZY(1\x94\xca1\x165m\xd6m\x90xs\xc7\x90d\x0c\xe3\xe9;\x9ec\xd3Q\xe6\x11<z\xff:\x97\x9cz\x86{\xdd\x82S\xfc_\xbcow,`i<\xdd\x0f\xe0^\xb12\xdc,\xf5\x08\xdeey\xbb\xf4o\xadx\xc8(\xd0\xab)\xc1\x7f\xbe<z\xderLp\xa0\x02\x0c\x87!+q\x90\xae\x17\xd0\\y04\x1f\xae\xd2x\xc2\x92\xd4\xd5\x04\x9c\x9c\xc7\x0e\xcbxb\x81\xab\xe4w\xf4\xa1\x9f5\xb1p\xf1\xdf\x12^\x00lA\x83\xe1KP\xdb\xa93\x83\x13\x19\xb8\xf7RA\xe8\xe7\xdcU\xfc\xff\xbcJ\x9d\xc2\xba \xd5\xd5>\x15X#=\xf9\xdf\xbe\xee.\xc5\x82c\r\xd6\xad\x88=\xfc\x9f\xf4%+\xf5\ry\xb7\xb2\xabN\x1a\xb5$\xb6\x8b\x7f2sT\x9eo//\xb3\xbe\xdc\xc8\xbc\xc40\xae/P\xef\x1a\x0bP\x96R\xa0p\xe5\x8a\xad\x11\xe5u\xaa\xcbR'
print(str(byte,'utf-8'))
```

I want to convert this byte to string and and this to a json file so I can take the string and convert it back to byte when I want to use it.
but when I try to convert it gives such an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wallet.py", line 126, in <module>
     print(str(byte,'utf-8'))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x9f in position 1: 
  invalid start byte`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could decode it like this,

```
>>> byte
b'\x7f\x9fKL\xaa\xe6\xc8\x8d\xdf865\xf1s\tR\xd6\xe8\x9c\x07\xae\x97\xe4\x0e\xe6\x08_CZY(1\x94\xca1\x165m\xd6m\x90xs\xc7\x90d\x0c\xe3\xe9;\x9ec\xd3Q\xe6\x11<z\xff:\x97\x9cz\x86{\xdd\x82S\xfc_\xbcow,i<\xdd\x0f\xe0^\xb12\xdc,\xf5\x08\xdeey\xbb\xf4o\xadx\xc8(\xd0\xab)\xc1\x7f\xbe\x15X#=\xf9\xdf\xbe\xee.\xc5\x82c\r\xd6\xad\x88=\xfc\x9f\xf4%+\xf5\ry\xb7\xb2\xabN\x1a\xb5$\xb6\x8b\x7f2sT\x9eo//\xb3\xbe\xdc\xc8\xbc\xc40\xae/P\xef\x1a\x0bP\x96R\xa0p\xe5\x8a\xad\x11\xe5u\xaa\xcbR'
>>> print(''.join(chr(x) for x in byte))
KLªæÈß865ñs     RÖè®ä_CZY(1Ê15mÖmxsÇd
y·²«N▒µ$¶2sTo//³¾ÜÈ¼Ä0®/Pï▒          ãé;cÓQæ<zÿ:z{ÝSü_¼ow,i<Ýà^±2Ü,Þey»ôo­xÈ(Ð«)Á¾X#=ùß¾î.Åc
                           PR på­åuªËR
```

You can see what is going on here,

```
>>> y = [chr(x) for x in byte]
>>> y
['\x7f', '\x9f', 'K', 'L', 'ª', 'æ', 'È', '\x8d', 'ß', '8', '6', '5', 'ñ', 's', '\t', 'R', 'Ö', 'è', '\x9c', '\x07', '®', '\x97', 'ä', '\x0e', 'æ', '\x08', '_', 'C', 'Z', 'Y', '(', '1', '\x94', 'Ê', '1', '\x16', '5', 'm', 'Ö', 'm', '\x90', 'x', 's', 'Ç', '\x90', 'd', '\x0c', 'ã', 'é', ';', '\x9e', 'c', 'Ó', 'Q', 'æ', '\x11', '<', 'z', 'ÿ', ':', '\x97', '\x9c', 'z', '\x86', '{', 'Ý', '\x82', 'S', 'ü', '_', '¼', 'o', 'w', ',', 'i', '<', 'Ý', '\x0f', 'à', '^', '±', '2', 'Ü', ',', 'õ', '\x08', 'Þ', 'e', 'y', '»', 'ô', 'o', '\xad', 'x', 'È', '(', 'Ð', '«', ')', 'Á', '\x7f', '¾', '\x15', 'X', '#', '=', 'ù', 'ß', '¾', 'î', '.', 'Å', '\x82', 'c', '\r', 'Ö', '\xad', '\x88', '=', 'ü', '\x9f', 'ô', '%', '+', 'õ', '\r', 'y', '·', '²', '«', 'N', '\x1a', 'µ', '$', '¶', '\x8b', '\x7f', '2', 's', 'T', '\x9e', 'o', '/', '/', '³', '¾', 'Ü', 'È', '¼', 'Ä', '0', '®', '/', 'P', 'ï', '\x1a', '\x0b', 'P', '\x96', 'R', '\xa0', 'p', 'å', '\x8a', '\xad', '\x11', 'å', 'u', 'ª', 'Ë', 'R']
>>> [ord(x) for x in y]
[127, 159, 75, 76, 170, 230, 200, 141, 223, 56, 54, 53, 241, 115, 9, 82, 214, 232, 156, 7, 174, 151, 228, 14, 230, 8, 95, 67, 90, 89, 40, 49, 148, 202, 49, 22, 53, 109, 214, 109, 144, 120, 115, 199, 144, 100, 12, 227, 233, 59, 158, 99, 211, 81, 230, 17, 60, 122, 255, 58, 151, 156, 122, 134, 123, 221, 130, 83, 252, 95, 188, 111, 119, 44, 105, 60, 221, 15, 224, 94, 177, 50, 220, 44, 245, 8, 222, 101, 121, 187, 244, 111, 173, 120, 200, 40, 208, 171, 41, 193, 127, 190, 21, 88, 35, 61, 249, 223, 190, 238, 46, 197, 130, 99, 13, 214, 173, 136, 61, 252, 159, 244, 37, 43, 245, 13, 121, 183, 178, 171, 78, 26, 181, 36, 182, 139, 127, 50, 115, 84, 158, 111, 47, 47, 179, 190, 220, 200, 188, 196, 48, 174, 47, 80, 239, 26, 11, 80, 150, 82, 160, 112, 229, 138, 173, 17, 229, 117, 170, 203, 82]
>>> bytes([ord(x) for x in y])
b'\x7f\x9fKL\xaa\xe6\xc8\x8d\xdf865\xf1s\tR\xd6\xe8\x9c\x07\xae\x97\xe4\x0e\xe6\x08_CZY(1\x94\xca1\x165m\xd6m\x90xs\xc7\x90d\x0c\xe3\xe9;\x9ec\xd3Q\xe6\x11<z\xff:\x97\x9cz\x86{\xdd\x82S\xfc_\xbcow,i<\xdd\x0f\xe0^\xb12\xdc,\xf5\x08\xdeey\xbb\xf4o\xadx\xc8(\xd0\xab)\xc1\x7f\xbe\x15X#=\xf9\xdf\xbe\xee.\xc5\x82c\r\xd6\xad\x88=\xfc\x9f\xf4%+\xf5\ry\xb7\xb2\xabN\x1a\xb5$\xb6\x8b\x7f2sT\x9eo//\xb3\xbe\xdc\xc8\xbc\xc40\xae/P\xef\x1a\x0bP\x96R\xa0p\xe5\x8a\xad\x11\xe5u\xaa\xcbR'
>>>
>>> len(y)
171
>>> len(byte)
171
```

Comment: I can converted it back to byte but python says that it isn't same with the original one.

Answer (score 0):

try to use this code:

```
print(byte.decode('latin-1'))
```

Comment: i also tried that but i get a similar error
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wallet.py", line 126, in <module>
    print(str(byte,'utf-8'))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x9f in position 1: invalid start byte`

Comment: As I understand is the byte has character that is not in ascii. as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22216798/6662697
you can see a suggestion how to encode it

Comment: `Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/encodings/cp1252.py", line 15, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,errors,decoding_table)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 7: character maps to <undefined>
` it gives this

Comment: And the decoding of `latin-1`?