# why do i get this error from the compiler?

Tags: python

i wrote a code on python in visual studio code

```
n=input(Give me the number)
v[n] = n-1
for i in range(n):
    s[i] = ""
state = n-1
while state == -1:
    i = 0
    if i == 0:
        state = state -1
        s[i] = "v"+i+1
    k = 0
    for j in range(n)    
        if v[j]<state:
            i = i+1
            s[i]= "v"+i+1
            k=1 
    state = state - 1
```

and i am getting this error i have used the compiler before and debug i am getting this error for first time

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\isido\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.1.0\python-files\lib\python\ptvsd\wrapper.py", line 1422, in done
    fut.result()
  File "c:\Users\isido\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.1.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd\futures.py", line 40, in result
    reraise(self._exc_info)
  File "c:\Users\isido\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.1.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd\futures.py", line 163, in callback
    x = it.send(fut.result())
  File "c:\Users\isido\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.1.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd\wrapper.py", line 1533, in on_configurationDone
    self.send_process_event(self.start_reason)
  File "c:\Users\isido\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.1.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd\wrapper.py", line 1671, in send_process_event
    self.send_event('process', **evt)
  File "c:\Users\isido\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.1.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd\ipcjson.py", line 279, in send_event
    body=kwargs,
  File "c:\Users\isido\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.1.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd\ipcjson.py", line 103, in _send
    content = json.dumps(payload).encode('utf-8')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 244, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\encoder.py", line 207, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\encoder.py", line 270, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xb5 in position 52: invalid start byte
```

i don't know what is it

Comment: Can you add a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve?

Comment: Invalid syntax near: `n=input(Give me the number)`

Comment: Invalid syntax near: `for j in range(n)`

Comment: `unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'` near `v[n] = n-1` since you need to cast the input to `int` first.

Comment: NameError: name `v` is not defined

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xa5 in position 0: invalid start byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22216076/unicodedecodeerror-utf8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xa5-in-position-0-invalid-s)