# How do you skip over characters that can't be decoded?

Tags: python, parsing, ascii

In Python, I am parsing through a CSV file using pandas `read_csv` function, which is working fine until the point where I come across a 'μ'. At this point, I get a `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb5 in position 56: invalid start byte`. What is the best approach to get past this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xa5 in position 0: invalid start byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22216076/unicodedecodeerror-utf8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xa5-in-position-0-invalid-s)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UnicodeDecodeError when reading CSV file in Pandas with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18171739/unicodedecodeerror-when-reading-csv-file-in-pandas-with-python)