# Cannot get the data from MySQL and render it in Django

Tags: python, mysql, django, utf-8

I launched the Django project to maintain service. Then I got the following error.

```
UnicodeDecodeError at /register/
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb7 in position 3: invalid start byte
```

It was very simple operation that render the page with template. Django says error happened in template file but it was decoded as UTF-8.

The working environments are,

```
- Python 3.6.10 installed by pyenv.
- Django 2.1.8
- macOS Catalina
```

**Update!!**

In error log, I found the erorr log about the mysql connection. I configured the test mysql DB externally in AWS RDS. So it would be the clue.

```
........
File "/Users/jinhoyoo/.pyenv/versions/3.6.10/envs/youha/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _fetch_all
  1186.             self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
File "/Users/jinhoyoo/.pyenv/versions/3.6.10/envs/youha/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __iter__
  54.         results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
File "/Users/jinhoyoo/.pyenv/versions/3.6.10/envs/youha/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  1065.             cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/Users/jinhoyoo/.pyenv/versions/3.6.10/envs/youha/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  100.             return super().execute(sql, params)
File "/Users/jinhoyoo/.pyenv/versions/3.6.10/envs/youha/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  68.         return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
File "/Users/jinhoyoo/.pyenv/versions/3.6.10/envs/youha/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in _execute_with_wrappers
  77.         return executor(sql, params, many, context)
File "/Users/jinhoyoo/.pyenv/versions/3.6.10/envs/youha/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in _execute
  85.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/Users/jinhoyoo/.pyenv/versions/3.6.10/envs/youha/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py" in execute
  71.             return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
........
```

Comment: Can you share the template code listing here?

Comment: Hello Jinho! Maybe this question can help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22216076/unicodedecodeerror-utf8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xa5-in-position-0-invalid-s

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll look for the reason with your comment.  ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason. MySQL 8.0.19 version has the problem. You should use the mysql version under 8.0.18 as client.

You can install mysql client only by `brew install mysql-client` then you'll get the mysql client 8.0.18. Then reinstall `mysqlclient` python module by following `https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python`.

Answer (score 1):

`B7` is hex for "middle dot" in latin1.  It sounds like your *client* is using latin1, but your database setup is expecting utf8.

See "best practice" in [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)

Comment: Thanks, Rick. It's a good suggestion. In my case, all data and code were encoded as UTF-8. Only the mysql client has a problem. ;-)