# Cannot import .csv file via pd.read_csv due to UTF-8 errors

Tags: python, pandas, csv, import, utf-8

I tried a lot of solution both in R and Python and gave up.

I am trying to read a huge .csv file (1.6 GB).

I cannot even import it with `pandas` (managed to import with R).

[image]

I start from simple importing. `pd.read_csv()` with reading of a file name gives the same result.

I receive an error: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb5 in position 0: invalid start byte`

Google this error and go this [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22216076/unicodedecodeerror-utf8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xa5-in-position-0-invalid-s)

From this question I try solutions as

```
`encoding = 'unicode_escape'`
```

It give me an error:

`UnicodeDecodeError: 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode byte 0x5c in position 0: \ at end of string`

This solution

```
`pd.read_csv('file_name.csv', engine='python')`
```

gives me an error:

```
`ParserError: NULL byte detected. This byte cannot be processed in Python's native csv library at the moment, so please pass in engine='c' instead`
```

If I set engine as 'c'

```
`taxi_2020 = pd.read_csv(path, engine = 'c')`
```

I again have
`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb5 in position 0: invalid start byte`

I also tried to use this

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("ISO-8859-1")
```

but it is not relevant for Python 3.6

**The more I try, the bigger is the decision tree of my errors.** R imports this data, but I also has issues with it, when I try to work with character columns. It says 'input string 1 is invalid UTF-8', when I try to convert a character column into date.

I am new to Python, so **I would greatly appreciate some help with a simple and universal solution how to import such data**. The dataset is huge, not sure if I can upload it anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may need to include encoding = "ISO-8859-1"

for your reference: 
[UnicodeDecodeError when reading CSV file in Pandas with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18171739/unicodedecodeerror-when-reading-csv-file-in-pandas-with-python)

Comment: I am will start to cry now... ahahahahhahahhahahaha