# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb0 in position 0: invalid start byte

Tags: python, neural-network, google-colaboratory

Does anyone know how to fix the below problem? I am using google colab to run my neural network and want to create confusion matrix using below array however couldn't solve the problem.

```
label_names_array = np.chararray(3, itemsize = 4).decode("utf-8")

for key, value in label_names_array.items():
  label_names_array[key] = value
label_names_array
```

> UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in ()
> ----> 1 label_names_array = np.chararray(3, itemsize = 4).decode("utf-8")
> 2
> 3 for key, value in label_names.items():
> 4   label_names_array[key] = value
> 5 label_names_array
>
> 1 frames
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/defchararray.py in
> decode(a, encoding, errors)
> 562     """
> 563     return _to_string_or_unicode_array(
> --> 564         *vec_string(a, object*, 'decode', _clean_args(encoding, errors)))
> 565
> 566
>
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb0 in position
> 0: invalid start byte

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22216076/unicodedecodeerror-utf8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xa5-in-position-0-invalid-s help you?

Comment: If you read the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.char.chararray.html?highlight=chararray#numpy.char.chararray) for `chararray` you will learn (1) It's recommended that you don't use it (2) If you do use it, you shouldn't use this constructor directly.

Answer (score -1):

there are several issues with your code: first of all I dont'seem to find an `.items()` method for a numpy array: it belongs to a Python `dictionary` I think.
So you could build a dictionary directly from your array using a constructor and skipping the for loop:

```
label_names_array = np.chararray(3, itemsize=4).decode("utf-8")
labels_dict = dict(np.ndenumerate(label_names_array))
```

What do you think?

You started asking from a very early point however. You should consider posting some code where you show how do you use the data and how you want to construct the confusion matrix.

What about trying with [scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html)?