# DataStax Encoding

Tags: encoding, cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise

I'm building DataStax Enterprise backup / restore utilities.

nodetool snapshot works fine.

the snapshot restore process is overly complex.

I am trying to get https://github.com/gianlucaborello/cassandradump to work.  The cassandradump utility is working fine, although I get the error:

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 42: invalid start byte

when it gets to the backup of the system.local table.

So, my question is:  how do I set the encoding for my cluster, or my keyspace, to UTF-8?  To test the cassandradump utility, I am using the command:

python cassandradump.py --keyspace system --export-file testdump.cql

I fear the answer may be that the encoding of the system keyspace is not my concern, but shouldn't that be configurable?

I have also seen this post: [UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode bytes in position 3-6: invalid data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6180521/unicodedecodeerror-utf8-codec-cant-decode-bytes-in-position-3-6-invalid-dat)

But, it doesn't seem applicable to the cassandradump utility.  It looks like the cassandradump utility has tried to allow for encoding as best it can.

Comment: 1) Not sure why you're backing the system keyspace, messing with the system keyspace in general is not a good idea unless you know what you're doing 2) If you're using DSE, the supported approach is the OpsCenter backup service which is built in.